# Last added image only shows in recyclerview

Tags: android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, picasso

I am using Picasso to retrieve the images from the firebase to the recyclerview.In one item, there are an image, title, and description. But If I have 2 items on my list. All Titles and descriptions are loading, but the image is only loading in the second item only.This is my code to retrieve the image from firebase URL.

```
     try{
            Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_add).into(holder.adIv);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            holder.adIv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add);
        }
```

Is that a weak reference to load all the images? What are the possible changes to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Picasso is slower than glide.

Use this:

`Glide.with(your activity).load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_add).into(holder.adiv);`

Instead of using picasso.

Before you try to load images from glide,you need to add a glide dependency.to add it,google it.